# Prove/Disprove$ \langle f,f\rangle = 2\int_0^{0.5} \left | f(t) \right |^2 \, dt -\int_{0.5}^1 \left | f(t) \right |^2 \, dt = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, inner-products

It's a part of proving an inner product space, I can't find a way to prove that nor disprove that
$$
\langle f,f\rangle = 2\int_0^{0.5} \left| f(t) \right|^2 \, dt -\int_{0.5}^1 \left | f(t) \right |^2 \, dt = 0 \Rightarrow f = 0$$

We know $C^1[0,1]$ are all the continuous functions $f[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with continous deravatives on $[0,1],$ the inner product that needs to be shown is over $C^1[0,1]$.

I can't see for example why [this](https://sketch.io/render/sk-2a7c2a7d1df8d4717815f18074bb2a0f.jpeg) can't be a possibility that will result in the fact that $f\neq0$ but still $\langle f,f\rangle = 0$

Comment: It seems that you understood everything properly: that thing is not an inner product.

Comment: Proper notation is $\langle f,f\rangle,$ not $<f,f>. \qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong. As a result, the bilinear form is not a inner product.

A counter example is given by
$$ f(t) = 2^t\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Try $f(x)=x^k$, where $k=\frac{\log_23-1}{2}.$